# Jquery UI button gets autoselected

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have created a simple dialog box with 2 buttons , but by default "Yes" is auto
selected .. here's the screenshot (http://img42.imageshack.us/img42/8805/butne.jpg)
Is there any way to remove that

```
$(function() {

$("#dialog-message").dialog({

    modal : true,
    resizable : false,
    show: "blind",
    draggable: false,
    width:350,
    overlay: {
                backgroundColor: '#000',
                opacity: 0.9
        },
    buttons : {
        "Yes":function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");

        },

        "No":function() {

            $(this).dialog("close");

        }

    }

});

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the focus to another element in your dialog content? Like this:

```
jQuery('SELECTOR').focus();
```

**EDIT**
if you dont have another element, call blur on your dialog buttons in the `show` method:

```
$("#dialog-message").dialog({
    modal : true,
    resizable : false,
    show: "blind",
    draggable: false,
    width:350,
    overlay: {
        backgroundColor: '#000',
        opacity: 0.9
    },
    buttons : {
        "Yes":function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");

        },

        "No":function() {

            $(this).dialog("close");

        }
    },
    open: function(event, ui) {
        $('.ui-button').blur();
    }

});
```

Comment: in that page there will be no other element so cannot focus on a different one.. :(

Comment: What about bluring the Button?

Comment: jQuery("#dialog-message .ui-button").blur()